# Using Templated Parameter Functions That Call Type Functions

Tags: c++, types, type-safety, c++-templates

So I was wondering if it is safe to use a private templated function that inside accesses a function of the type that is passed in. Keep in mind that i ensure myself that only these two types can be passed in and the function exists in both structures. The code runs like I would expect but I have concerns about its safty. Is there a better way to achieve the same outcome? Thank you in advance :)

Types:

```
struct Typestruct1
{
    int size = 4;

    int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
};


struct Typestruct2
{
    int size = 8;

    int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
};
```

Class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void printSizes() {
        std::cout << getSize(t1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << getSize(t2) << std::endl;
    }

private:
    template<typename Type>
    int getSize(Type structType) {
        return structType.getSize();
    }

private:
    Typestruct1 t1;
    Typestruct2 t2;
};
```

Usage:

```
MyClass myClass;
myClass.printSizes();
```

As I expected it prints:

4
8

Comment: what "safety" are you concerned about?

Comment: why not simply `std::cout << t1.getSize() << std::endl;` and `std::cout << t2.getSize() << std::endl;` ? Whats the purpose of the method template?

Comment: This is just pseudo code, in my real class it takes a buffer and then decides on which type to use. This code was just written to reflect my question regarding safety.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with what you are doing here.

Comment: `MyClass::getSize` takes its parameter by value, and so would make a copy and call a method on that copy, rather on the original data member. This doesn't matter in the example shown; it may matter in the real code.

Comment: If I show you [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/7PvvW8qKf) do you understand what's happening or do you need more info ?

Comment: Hello Igor, that issue doesent exist in my real code. However thank you for pointing it out :).

Comment: Viral taco, I understand your code. That problem is that this example I provided is a simpflied version. In my real version the underlying type is not the same (in the test case it is int). I was more concerned if it is okay to use templated parameters that in the function body call a function of that type if you ensure it is only used with types that contain a function with the same name: Typestruct1 and Typestruct2 contain the function getSize().

Comment: it would even be safe to call the member function template with a type that does not have a `getSize()`, because if you do you will get a compiler error. Templates can be used for type erasure and that does bypass the type system, but there is no type erasure here (much more would be needed)

Comment: @H_H `This is just pseudo code, in my real class it takes a buffer and then decides on which type to use. This code was just written to reflect my question regarding safety. ` Could you make your question more suitable to solution you are looking for. If you trying to reinvent some serializing to save your data in some binary form e.g. ASN1, Google Protocol Buffers, Apache Avro, Dbus, COM/DCOM etc - you'd better do some research instead. As well as there is some sizeof operator and structure aliment added by compiler.

Comment: @H_H This question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would highlight three different approaches:

a) If you are about to use either of the two types only (`Typestruct1` and `Typestruct2`) as a function argument and if these two have a similar structure, it would make more sense to use polymorphism instead of creating a template function. You would create an interface, an abstract base class for `Typestruct1` and `Typestruct2` with a pure virtual function `virtual int getSize() = 0`, which you will have to override in each derived class. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct TypestructBase {
    virtual int getSize() = 0;
};

struct Typestruct1 : TypestructBase {
    int size = 4;
    int getSize() override {
        return size;
    }
};

struct Typestruct2 : TypestructBase {
    int size = 8;
    int getSize() override {
        return size;
    }
};

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {
        t1 = new Typestruct1();
        t2 = new Typestruct2();
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        delete t1;
        delete t2;
    }
    void printSizes() {
        std::cout << getSize(t1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << getSize(t2) << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int getSize(TypestructBase *structType) {
        return structType->getSize();
    }

    TypestructBase *t1;
    TypestructBase *t2;
};

int main() {
    MyClass myObject;
    myObject.printSizes();

    return 0;
}
```

b) If `Typestruct1` and `Typestruct2` don't have a common base and you would like to use the template function with these two types as arguments, you could use the explicit template instantiation to notify the compiler about it:

```
template int MyClass::getSize(Typestruct1);
template int MyClass::getSize(Typestruct2);
```

c) Or you might want to use template specialization if you want to provide different function implementations conditional on arg type in your template function:

```
template<>
int MyClass::getSize(Typestruct1 structType) {
    // Do something with the type Typestruct1
}

template<>
int MyClass::getSize(Typestruct2 structType) {
    // Do something with the type Typestruct2
}
```